# Check type of variable within Ti-Nspire function

Tags: ti-nspire

In Javascript there is the string `typeof variable` which returns either: number, string, array, object.

Is there a similar function I can run in the Ti-Nspire to tell if the variable is a number, string, or matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `gettype(var)` function will return the string with variable type in it (`"LIST"`, `"MAT"`, `"EXPR"`, `"NUM"`, `"STR"`, or `"NONE"`)

Answer (score 1):

<del>No, but if you give an example of why you want to do do this, somebody may be able to help you.</del>

Edit: An update of the language has added a function that solves OP's problem, making this answer out of date.

Comment: Incorrect; `gettype(var)` provides this exact functionality. An example usage case would be writing a function that can accept data as either a list or a matrix.

Comment: @Johannes This is a new function that did not exist at the time of my answer, but now the function exists, so the problem is solved.